# MySQL Left Join with multiple rows

Tags: mysql, join, rows

I'm looking to join a 2 tables but the second table has a one to many relation. Can I omit the entire row if any of the lines have a certain value? Let me explain more.

```
User table

id name email
1  bob  bob@test.com
2  foo  foo@test.com


Music table

id userId
1  1
1  2
2  1
3  1
2  2
```

Say I don't want it to show the user if he has a relation to music table id 2. Also looking for distinct user.

If I try something like this it will still show both users.

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN music m ON u.id = m.userId WHERE m.id <> 3
```

I want it to check all the rows and if it has the id 3, it won't show. I hope I made sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to your ON condition?  `ON u.id=muserId and m.id <> 1`

Comment: I just did but it's returning the same set. But I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Your query should return only 1 row with user `foo` so where's the problem?

Comment: @SubRed Sorry about that but the table might not have been clear. I adjusted that. See right now if I don't want to join the user if he has a music id of 3, it will still show up because he has an id of 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh I see try my answer below. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using sub query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT userId FROM music WHERE id=3)
```

This query means to select all users if their id is not related with music.id 3.

Comment: Perfect! Sorry for the late response, my query was a little bit more complicated than this so I was trying to match it but it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.